# How to display XML-like data in a web app?

Tags: mysql, xml, html

I have XML-like data stored in a MySQL database and now I need to retrieve it and display it on a webpage. I would preferably like to have it collapsible, but if I can just get it displaying in a tabular, decent format that would be awesome.

It also includes a date and time value. Ideally I would like to sort by this, but I think that is asking too much...

Here is a sample of what I am dealing with (this in a varchar, in 1 coloumn, in 1 row):

```
  <patroldetail value=32-3795>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>TAG_COMPLETED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:52:51</Time>
  <Tag>12903 Reception</Tag>
</patroltag>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>TAG_COMPLETED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:52:01</Time>
  <Tag>12922 - Tuckshop</Tag>
</patroltag>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>TAG_COMPLETED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:50:57</Time>
  <Tag>12905 - Silo 1</Tag>
</patroltag>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>TAG_COMPLETED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:50:34</Time>
  <Tag>12919 - Eastern Fence</Tag>
</patroltag>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>TAG_COMPLETED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:50:19</Time>
  <Tag>PATROL_REMINDER</Tag>
</patroltag>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>PATROL_STARTED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:50:19</Time>
  <Tag></Tag>
</patroltag>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>TAG_COMPLETED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:58:16</Time>
  <Tag>13882</Tag>
</patroltag>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>PATROL_FINISHED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:59:48</Time>
  <Tag>PATROL_REMINDER</Tag>
</patroltag>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>TAG_COMPLETED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:56:35</Time>
  <Tag>12935 - Compressor Room</Tag>
</patroltag>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>TAG_COMPLETED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:56:11</Time>
  <Tag>12920 - Gantry</Tag>
</patroltag>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>TAG_COMPLETED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:55:35</Time>
  <Tag>12827 Northeast Corner</Tag>
</patroltag>
    <patroltag>
  <Type>TAG_COMPLETED</Type>
  <Date>05/09/2015</Date>
  <Time>22:54:58</Time>
  <Tag>12851 - Main Gate</Tag>
</patroltag>
</patroldetail>
```

Background: I am creating a BI app, and this data was stored in one coloumn/row as it was far more economical (reducing the rows required in the table by 50x in most cases). I assumed (I think incorrectly) that this would be an easy feat, but have yet to find anything out there that solves my problem.

Any guidance around how to get this displaying in a web-app would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommendations

1. ***XML-like***: No, don't bother.  Make it real XML or you're on your own.  There is
   no definition of *XML-like* that any library author would support.
2. **XML**: Use [Ace](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about), an embeddable code editor written in JavaScript.  It can display many languages with syntax highlighting, including XML (and allow editing too if you so desire).  It can also collapse elements as you request.

Comment: Yup, I tend to agree.... Picking up the pieces here. I'll give that a go, looks like it'll do the job. Tanks!